# Convertir hexadecimal en float

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con php y me llega unas coordenadas en formato hexadecimal (esto no se puede cambiar porque es un mensaje que se recibe desde la red SigFox). Los valores que se reciben son `C40B3986`y `4564AF79` y los valores en float serian `-556.8988`y `3658.967`. He usado este código que encontre por google para hacer la transformación:

```
function hex2float($strHex) 
{
    $hex = sscanf($strHex, "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x");
    $hex = array_reverse($hex);
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $hex));
    $array = unpack("dnum", $bin);
    return $array['num'];
}
```

Pero los resultados que se obtienen difieren bastante de lo esperado: `2.9704245515207E-65`y `6.7994010560009E-225`. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?

Comment: Mira esta aproximación por si te sirve de ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/a/19975815/5675636, pero los valores obtenidos para tus valores de ejemplo serían float(-100.5897337) y float(116.4226425), no se corresponde a tus valores esperados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí tienes una función la cual te puede ayudar:

```
<?php

$string = "C40B3986";

function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
  $v = hexdec($strHex);
  $x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
  $exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
  return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23);
}

$float = hexTo32Float($string);
echo "El valor Float de ".$string." es: ".$float."<br>";

?>
```

Esta función convierte un string hexadecimal en un número flotante IEEE 754 de 32 bits.

La puedes ver funcionando [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90d4e51f3ad7e4743021cde2a09008d388ca52b4):

**Editado**

Según la acotación de @aloMalbarez:

> pareciera que se come el bit de signo así que habría que agregarlo

quedaría así:

```
<?php

$string = "C40B3986";

function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
  $v = hexdec($strHex);
  $x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
  $exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
  return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23)*($v>>31==0?1:-1);
}

$float = hexTo32Float($string);
echo "El valor Float de ".$string." es: ".$float."<br>";

?>
```

Puedes verlo con su acotación [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70bb2582c8f777f499408e2c2e16f045762def8f).

Comment: pareciera que se come el bit de signo así que habría que agregarlo, onda `return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23)*($v>>31==0?1:-1);` [ver online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70bb2582c8f777f499408e2c2e16f045762def8f).

Comment: Gracias por tu acotación @aloMalbarez ya lo arreglo

Comment: ¡Gracias! Funciona perfecto. Me has ahorrado un buen dolor de cabeza